# better integration with asp.net entity framework or Nhibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, entity-framework-4

I'm have a lot of time using hibernate (JPA) in java, but i recently am in a new job in which had used the platform of .net and they ask me to develop and application with certain standards and one of the them requirements are related with the using of ORM, but i have seen looking for resources and frameworks that exit's two first the nhibernate and second the entity framework. So my question it's what of two have the best integration with .net **(Visual Studio 2008)** and also  give's the best performance to manage the info.

**Edit**
Notice that my application it's mvc app

Comment: possible duplicate of [nhibernate, entity framework, active records or linq2sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADO.NET Entity Framework integrates better with Visual Studio 2008+ in terms of visual class designer etc.

Even though the Entity Framework supports "Peristence Ignorance" like NHibernate/Hibernate does, NHibernate is much more mature.

If you don't need a clean separation of concerns regarding data access layer and the domain layer, the Entity Framework allows you more rapid development, since you can generate classes from your database from within Visual Studio. Data contexts for persistence purposes will already be set up and ready to use.

If you need to setup a professional environment with a persistent ignorant domain layer, dependency injection, etc., I would go for nHibernate. Since you already have experience with that and its more mature (more features).